# Как добавить свой using при создании проекта в Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

При создании нового проекта Visual Studio добавляет:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

Как добавить в этот шаблон свой using? Например:

```
using static System.Console;
```

Comment: наверное не в проект, а в файл?

Comment: @Grundy Собственно, да. Файл Program.cs в составе проекта.

Comment: Меню File > Export Template.

Comment: [Creating Custom Project and ItemTemplates in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247121.aspx)

Comment: @Grundy Ок.Разобрался. Всем спасибо.

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 2):

Экспортировать проект или элемент проекта из текущего решения в шаблон, на основе которого можно будет создать новые проекты.